# Bottom div is overlapping

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

We are trying to create Email application. We are facing issue in message body div which is over lapping with header div (contains To/CC/Subject). On page load everything looks good but when start adding email id's in To field then body section is getting overlapped with header.

```
.MainDiv{
position: fixed;
    width: 65%;
    max-width: 890px;
    height: 80%;
    max-height: 1100px;
    z-index: 1000 !important;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px;
    top: 10%;
    left: 23%;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
}

.Header{
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 5px 25px;
    min-height: 100px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 99%;
    border: solid 1px green;
    padding: 10px 20px 0px;
    overflow: initial !important;{
}

.Body{
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 1px red;
    top: 175px;
    bottom: 72px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[ReplyMessage_Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/067JU.png)

Comment: share a link to code or share a fiddle of code

Comment: send you full code

Comment: Are you sure the header is overlapping the body ? Or is it the body overlapping the header ?

Comment: The CSS of your header is also broken. See the curly braces.

Comment: @rach8garg : Yes body is overlapping header. and the curly braces is a Typo. Missed it while pasting css. Please refer attached screenshot

Comment: @satyajitrout https://jsfiddle.net/uh32n683/17/ ..try to add text in header it will overlap body section

Comment: JS fiddler link:  `https://jsfiddle.net/uh32n683/17/` 
Add content in header section (in above js fiddler link) it will overlap message body section. Body height should be automatically adjusted.

Comment: you could either remove position absolut on .Body or remove top and set bottom to 0 on .Body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `position: absolute;` it's causing problem

```css
.MainDiv{
position: relative;
    width: 65%;
    max-width: 890px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 1100px;
    z-index: 1000 !important;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px;
    top: 10%;
    left: 23%;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    border: solid 1px black;
    overflow-y : auto;
}

.Header{
    clear: both;
    
    min-height: 100px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px green;    
    overflow: initial !important;
}

.Body{
    border: solid 1px red;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
h2{
  background-color:yellow;
}
h3{
  background-color:teal;
}
```

```html
<div class = "MainDiv"  >

<div class ="Header" contenteditable="true">
<h2>
Header  ygygyggyggygyyygyggygyyg yyfyffyyffyfyfy yfyfyfyfy gygygygygyyg yggygygyyggy gygyygygyyggygygygygy yggyygygyggyy uhuuuguug guuggugu
</h2>
</div>
<div class= "Body" contenteditable="true">
<h3>
Message Body
</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @ satyajit,  After removing "position:absolute", Message body is NOT overlapping from the top.. but when i resize window from the bottom, Messagebody content is going outside of MainDiv.

Comment: @Saurabh check now i have edited it just remove position: fixed...please accept the answer if its correct now

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be overdoing it. Here is what you need perhaps.

```css
.MainDiv{
}

.Header{
    margin: 0 5px 10px;
    min-height: 100px;
    display: block;
    border: solid 1px green;
    padding: 10px 20px 0px;
}

.Body{
    border: solid 1px red;
    margin: 0 5px 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 10px 20px 0px;
    height:300px;
    max-height:600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainDiv">
  <div class="Header">

  </div>
  <div class="Body">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks... Height of main div is fixed so if header is pushing body div down then body div should get scroll bar.